# SPARQL queries fail

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, linked-data

This [ontology](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf) has these [classes](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%20PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%20%0D%0A%20SELECT%20%3Fclass%0D%0A%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk%2Fphillip.lord%2Fscratch%2Fpizza.rdf%3E%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Fclass%20rdf%3Atype%20owl%3AClass%0D%0A%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl) and this number of  [triples](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%20PREFIX%20pizza%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk%2Fphillip.lord%2Fscratch%2Fpizza.rdf%23%3E%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%20SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20AS%20%3Fno%29%20%0D%0A%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk%2Fphillip.lord%2Fscratch%2Fpizza.rdf%3E%0D%0A%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl). For completeness, here are the [triples](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%20SELECT%20*%0D%0A%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk%2Fphillip.lord%2Fscratch%2Fpizza.rdf%3E%0D%0A%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl).

This query works as expected:

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 SELECT ?p
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE {
  ?p rdfs:subClassOf pizza:PizzaTopping
 }
```

as shown [here](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=%20PREFIX%20pizza%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncl.ac.uk%2Fpizza%23%3E%0D%0A%20PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%20SELECT%20%3Fp%0D%0A%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk%2Fphillip.lord%2Fscratch%2Fpizza.rdf%3E%0D%0A%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fp%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%20pizza%3APizzaTopping%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl).

However, this query does not produce the expected results:

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE { 
 ?Name ?Relation pizza:MushroomTopping .
 ?Relation owl:inverseOf pizza:isToppingOf .
 OPTIONAL { 
  ?Name2 ?Relation2 pizza:HamTopping .
  ?Relations2 owl:inverseOf pizza:isToppingOf . 
 }
 FILTER(?Name2 = ?PizzaName)
 }
```

A simplified version also fails:

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 SELECT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE { 
 ?Name ?Relation pizza:NonVegetarianPizza .
 }
```

These desired queries probably share the same fault:

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 SELECT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE { ?p rdf:type pizza:Pizza;
            pizza:hasTopping ?t.
         ?t rdf:type pizza:TomatoTopping
       }
```

and

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 SELECT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE
 {
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
  owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping;
  owl:someValuesFrom pizza:MushroomTopping ] .
 }
```

and

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 SELECT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE
 {
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
    owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom pizza:MozzarellaTopping ] .
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
    owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom pizza:PeperonSausageTopping ] .
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
    owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom pizza:TomatoTopping ] .
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplified query:

```
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.ncl.ac.uk/pizza#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 SELECT *
 FROM <http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf>
 WHERE { 
 ?Name ?Relation pizza:NonVegetarianPizza .
 }
```

shouldn't return anything.  In the data you linked to, `pizza:NonVegetarianPizza` only appears as an subject, never as an object.  Did you have some reason to expect this query to return some results?

Comment: My goal was to identify the topping related to NonVegetarianPizza. The other queries have a similar goal. How should I re-write to produce those results?

Comment: You'll need first to make precise what you mean by ‘related to'.

Comment: I'll look at this again and be back to you:

http://rhizomik.net/redefer-services/render?rdf=http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/phillip.lord/scratch/pizza.rdf&format=RDF/XML&mode=svg&rules=http://rhizomik.net:8080/html/redefer/rdf2svg/showclasshierarchy.jrule

Comment: I looked at the graph and believe there is a solution for this: pizza with SweetPepperTopping and ParmesanTopping. How to compose that query (a variation of the last listed failed example)

Comment: What do you mean that you believe that there's a solution for that?  A pizza with SweetPepperTopping and ParmesanTopping isn't necessarily a NonVegetarianPizza or a non NonVegetarianPizza;  it would depend on what else could be on the pizza.  To get results about those sorts of things, you'll need to do OWL reasoning anyhow.  You can do some limited kinds of OWL reasoning with a SPARQL query, but not arbitrary OWL reasoning.

Comment: Note that (from the close reasons): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."  I think you need to pin down some specific results you *expect* to get.  Only then can we help to explain why you're not getting them and what you could do to get them.